# Disable button after form submission bootstrap angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a button which loads up a form with some columns on submission of that form  pop up closes and data is sent to service layer.

I want that button to get disabled which I clicked at the first place to open pop up after submission of the form on the pop up.

Answer (score 0):

There is a dedicated variable for this `$submitted`. See [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#$submitted):

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable visible from the view ($scope or other name if you are using controllerAs). Let's assume that you are using $scope. So, you can set $scope.sending = true. When the task has ended, you can set $scope.sending = false.

Now, let's see the view. In button tag, you can use ng-disabled directive with the $scope.sending variable. With this, if $scope.sending is true, the button will be disabled, and if it is false, the button will be enabled.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Set the ng-disabled directive of pupup button once you click on form submit button 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled